# dummyrepository data foreign key with random id

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, repository-pattern

There are two dummyrepositorys in my project, one for questions and one for answers. The questions are multiple choise, so they can have multiple answers. My **question** model:

```
public class Question : BaseClass
{
    public Question() : base()
    {

    }

    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

And an **Answer** belongs to a question

```
public class Answer : BaseClass
{
    public Answer() : base()
    {

    }
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; } 
}
```

They both extend the **BaseClass** which has some custom fields.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected BaseClass()
    {
        UniqueIdentifier = RandomIdentifier(20);
    }

    public string UniqueIdentifier { get; set; }

    private static string RandomIdentifier(int length)
    {
     //returns an unique identifier 
    }
}
```

My **dummyQuestionRepository** looks like:

```
public class DummyQuestionRepository : IQuestionRepository
{

    private  List<Question> _questions;

    public DummyQuestionRepository()
    {
        _questions = new List<Question>();
        _questions.Add(new Question { Value = "Favourit food?" });
        _questions.Add(new Question { Value = "Who is the president?" });
        _questions.Add(new Question { Value = "Favourit movie?" });
    }

    public List<Question> GetAll()
    {
        return _questions;
    }
    public void Create(Question q)
    {
        _questions.Add(q);
    }

   //removed the non relevant functions
}
```

My **dummyAnswerRepository**

```
class DummyAnswerRepository
{
    private  List<Answer> _answers;

    public DummyAnswerRepository()
    {
        _answers = new List<Answer>();
        _answers.Add(new Answer { Value = "pizza" });
        _answers.Add(new Answer { Value = "fries" });
        _answers.Add(new Answer { Value = "Bush" });
        _answers.Add(new Answer { Value = "Obama" });
        _answers.Add(new Answer { Value = "titanic" });
        _answers.Add(new Answer { Value = "lion king" });
    }

   public List<Answer> GetAll()
    {
        return _answers;
    }

    public void Create(Answer a)
    {
        _answers.Add(a);

    }
}
```

As you might notice the baseclass has an UniqueIdentifier variable. This variable is used to create a unique value in the online database  (the id can't be used because users could make the same id when working offline), answers should have UniqueIdentifier as foreign key on question.
How should I get/set the answers from a question so I can load them in my views?

Comment: When you connect to you on-line database a Synchronization must occur between the local database and the on-line database.  When you are offline a temporary id must be created for any new items added.  Then when you connect to the on-line database a permanent id must be obtained and then you have to replace the temporary id with the permanent id.

Comment: @jdweng i would really like to use the code I posted. i wouldn't need a value that remember if its synced and the need to set the id on callback from the server. I might change the code though but i would still like to know how to solve the question i posted.

Comment: Is the on-line database being used by one or more than one user? How is the ID obtained when connected on-line?  When a database is used by multiple users you have to make sure a unique id is generated for each new item.  You first have to solve this issue before you solve the synchronization issue.

Comment: @jdweng It's used by multiple users, its not an synchronization issue its an issue of initializing dummy data, the whole sync part is not relevant but ive added it to explain why im using an unique value instead of an auto increment value.

Comment: How can you issue unique values when multiple users are generating the unique values randomly. You design has issues. To uniquely generate values each user must be given an orthogonal seed which to generate the unique random values based on a prime numbers. The more users you have the larger the prime number must be.  A Guid even though it is 2^128 doesn't 100% guarantee uniqueness. You should read up on cell phone technology. When a cell phone connects to a base station a PN number is assigned which is based on the id number on the phone so each cell phone won't interfere with other phones.

Comment: @jdweng again syncing isnt the problem the id i create  has 26^36 possiblilitys and adds the microseconds its added. So you have a chance of 26^36 and you need to get that posibility in the same microsecond.

Comment: It depends on how robust you want your code.  I personally look for code that runs 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good way is to use [Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) which will help you to merge user databases because Guid has 2^128 unique values. Use [Guid.NewGuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate new unique value

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected BaseClass()
    {
        UniqueIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid UniqueIdentifier { get; set; }
}
```

To add foreign keys you can implement method similar to [Entity Framework Seed method](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx) when answers and questions will create in one place and then added to your repositories. Just delete code which creates new entities from repositories constructors and use code like below:

```
public class DataBaseInitializer
{
    public void Seed(IQuestionRepository questionRepository, DummyAnswerRepository answerRepository)
    {
        var q1 = new Question { Value = "Favourit food?" };
        var q2 = new Question { Value = "Who is the president?" });
        var q3 = new Question { Value = "Favourit movie?" });

        questionRepository.Create(q1);
        questionRepository.Create(q2);
        questionRepository.Create(q3);

        answerRepository.Create(new Answer { Value = "pizza", Question = q1 });
        answerRepository.Create(new Answer { Value = "fries", Question = q1 });
        answerRepository.Create(new Answer { Value = "Bush", Question = q2 });
        answerRepository.Create(new Answer { Value = "Obama", Question = q2 });
        answerRepository.Create(new Answer { Value = "titanic", Question = q3 });
        answerRepository.Create(new Answer { Value = "lion king", Question = q3 });
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not creating an unique id i create one based on timestamp in miliseconds with an random 36 values long string (the chance of that being equal is less than 26^36) and than it has to be in the milisecond. The question is about setting a foreign key when using a random id.

Comment: Oh, now I understand, sorry for my answer. For your problem you should implement the logic similar to DataBase Seed method - your answers should be created in the same place with qustions and then you be able to do something like `_answers.Add(new Answer { Value = "Bush", Question = question2 });`

Comment: but how can i add the question to the answer should i pass the dummyquestionrepository in the constructor and get the question there?

Comment: @SvenB Use Seed method instead of constructor creation. Delete answers initialization from repository constructor and use DataBaseInitializer like in the answer above. The other way is to retrieve questions via GetAll method but it will be incomplete solution because your initialization code will separate to different parts of your app.

Comment: @VladimMatynov thanks for the answer, should I create a singleton for the repositorys so i have to initialize them only once and call the Databaseinitialiser on startup?

Comment: I'm not sure with your app design and can't answer about singletones. If your repositories just store data in memory and don't retrieve it from other datasources then you should store it in memory via singletone pattern or in other way. If users can create their own questions and answers you will need save this information after application teardown and load on next startup, will not you?
And, yes, call Databaseinitialiser on startup and then use initialized datasource (repositories).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99552/discussion-between-sven-b-and-vadim-martynov).